# R- Break axis matplot function

Tags: r, axis, break

I need to break an axis from 0.5 to 1.5. My code is:

```
matplot( wxyz$days_until_last_pay, wxyz[,c(2,3,4,5)], type=c("b"), pch=1, col=1:4,
         main="x![enter image description here][1]", cex.main=0.8)
legend("bottomright", inset=c(0,-0.57), fill=NULL, 
       legend = c("mean","median","max", "min"), col=1:4, pch=1, cex=0.8) 
library("plotrix")
axis.break(axis=2,1,,2,style="zigzag", brw=0.03)
```

But I only get a line in it. This is not breaking the axis.
[image]

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: you could just change the labels and subtract whatever the size of the break is, from data above the break...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axis.break` puts a break into an existing `plot`, so if the axis is not "broken" it will not work.

One suggestion is to make two plots on top of each other and set their `ylim` be so that there is a gap between 0.5 and 1.5, e.g.

```
## Some data, set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(c(rnorm(50, 2, 0.1),
              rnorm(50, 0.2, 0.05),
              rnorm(50, 0.3, 0.05)),
              byrow=FALSE, ncol=3)

## Split the device into two subplots
par(mfrow = c(2,1))

## Set the bottom margin of the top plot to 0.1
par(mar=c(0.1,4.1,4.1,2))

## Top plot (first column of the matrix)
plot(dat[,1], add=T, type="l", xaxt="n", ylab="", ylim=c(1.5, 2.5))

## Set the top margin of the bottom plot to 0.1
par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,0.1,2))

## Bottom plot
matplot(dat[,2:3], type="l", col=2:3, ylab="", ylim=c(0, 0.5))
```

This gives you something like:
[image]